# what exactly missed in package or in my code in angular cli?

Tags: angular, dependencies, angular-cli

I have worked in Angular2 CLI project and i have installed mydatepicker package from [here](https://github.com/kekeh/mydatepicker) it works completely perfect but when i run `ng serve` command for init application it throws below error once, afterwards application run as it is perfect so what actually i missed or is it package error ?

```
ERROR in multi script-loader!./src/assets/js/modernizr.js script-loader!./~/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js script-loader!./~/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js script-loader!./~/jquery-migrate/dist/jquery-migrate.min.js script-loader!./src/assets/js/plugins.js script-loader!./src/mydatepicker/bundles/mydatepicker.umd.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'E:\Project\PROFILE\src\mydatepicker\bundles\mydatepicker.umd.js' in 'E:\Project\PROFILE'
 @ multi script-loader!./src/assets/js/modernizr.js script-loader!./~/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js script-loader!./~/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js script-loader!./~/jquery-migrate/dist/jquery-migrate.min.js script-loader!./src/assets/js/plugins.js script-loader!./src/mydatepicker/bundles/mydatepicker.umd.js
```

Comment: Please share the angular cli version you are using as well as your module where you import mydatepicker so i can try to replicate.

Comment: try to serve your app in JIT mode (AOT = false): `ng serve -aot false`

Comment: @Manu Patel How do you resolve tht error .., could pls tell me

Answer (score 1):

```
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js",
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
]
```

have you added this in *angular-cli.json* file?

Comment: I have added this in my angClient Json but still i am facing an issue like `ERROR in multi script-loader!./~/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js script-loader!./~/boo
tstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js`  @Umesh Patadiya

Comment: have you added it in the same sequence as I wrote above?